Installing Airbnb eslint config in TS-enabled Vue application
I have a problem, when I create an app through create-vue and then try to install Airbnb https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/eslint-config-airbnb, I get an error I can't fix it.enter image description here
My package.json:
{
  "name": "ttt",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check \"build-only {@}\" --",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --build --force",
    "lint": "eslint . --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pinia": "^2.2.6",
    "vue": "^3.5.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node22": "^22.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.9.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.1.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^10.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^14.1.3",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.1",
    "eslint": "^9.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.30.0",
    "npm-run-all2": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "~5.6.3",
    "vite": "^5.4.10",
    "vite-plugin-vue-devtools": "^7.5.4",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.1.10"
  }
}

My eslint.config.js:
import pluginVue from 'eslint-plugin-vue'
import vueTsEslintConfig from '@vue/eslint-config-typescript'
import skipFormatting from '@vue/eslint-config-prettier/skip-formatting'
export default [
  {
    name: 'app/files-to-lint',
    files: ['**/*.{ts,mts,tsx,vue}'],
  },

  {
    name: 'app/files-to-ignore',
    ignores: ['**/dist/**', '**/dist-ssr/**', '**/coverage/**'],
  },
  ...pluginVue.configs['flat/essential'],
  ...vueTsEslintConfig(),
  skipFormatting,
]

and when I install @vue/eslint-config-airbnb
I get an error:

$ npm add --dev @vue/eslint-config-airbnb @rushstack/eslint-patch
npm WARN config dev Please use --include=dev instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ttt@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@9.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^9.14.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^8.2.0" from @vue/eslint-config-airbnb@8.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR!   @vue/eslint-config-airbnb@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-11-14T16_43_15_598Z-eresolve-report.txt


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-11-14T16_43_15_598Z-debug-0.log


The next thing I did was this:
npm add --dev @vue/eslint-config-airbnb @rushstack/eslint-patch --legacy-peer-deps
Next, I'm having trouble figuring out where to put this in:
require(‘@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution’)

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    ‘plugin:vue/vue3-essential’,
    ‘@vue/eslint-config-airbnb’
  ]
}

I'm using ES modules
Would welcome help and explanations on how I can do this. Thank you in advance.
I tried to do this:
import pluginVue from 'eslint-plugin-vue'
import vueTsEslintConfig from '@vue/eslint-config-typescript'
import skipFormatting from '@vue/eslint-config-prettier/skip-formatting'
import airbnbConfig from '@vue/eslint-config-airbnb 

export default [
  {
    name: 'app/files-to-lint',
    files: ['**/*.{ts,mts,tsx,vue}'],
  },

  {
    name: 'app/files-to-ignore',
    ignores: ['**/dist/**', '**/dist-ssr/**', '**/coverage/**'],
  },

  ...pluginVue.configs['flat/essential'],
  ...vueTsEslintConfig(),
  ...airbnbConfig(), // Add Airbnb config here
  skipFormatting,
]

but when I tried to test it via npm run lint I got an error

The package was updated a year ago, and eslint 9 is recent. See https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-config-airbnb/issues/65 . I'd advise against using 9 if you don't want to deal with various compatibility issues. Despite 8 reached eol, it may have less problems with other tools and packages
